# In Chrome (or a different browser), is there a way to change what is displayed when a site cannot be reached?

Tags: browser, browser-plugin

Note--I don't want to actually reach the can't-be-reached sites.  I just want to replace the diagnostic displayed with a message or image of my own choosing.

Comment: You have to connect to get a 404.  I'm talking about when you can't even connect.  The message I'm talking about is browser generated.